# cgminer: how to read the ASIC temperture

Tags: cgminer, mac, asic

I don't mind buying an IR thermometer but it there a way to read the temperature of the ASIC from the command line? I am using cgminer.

Comment: You could write a program to read cgminer's log. I could write a script to do that if you post a log from your ASIC.

Comment: Hi, in my ~/.cgminer there are no files. In the OSX console app nothing comes up if I search for cgminer, nor gekko, nor miner. Where is this log of which you speak?